# Algorithm for masking time when the signal is above a threshold

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qelapsedtimer

I have a realtime signal from a sensor. I need logic to implement a **masking time** once the signal is above a threshold. As shown below:

[image]

Here the signal (in blue) crosses a threshold. And I need to **mask** for any checks for the threshold for a period (masking time). (In this way I can detect only the *positive pulse*, similarly, I have another check for *negative pulse*)

See the code below:

```
static QTime time(QTime::currentTime());
// calculate two new data points:
double key = time.elapsed()/1000.0; // time elapsed since start of demo, in seconds
static double lastKey;

if(a_vertical> onThreshold && key-lastKey >0.2) // is this check correct for masking time?
    {
        ui->rdo_btn_vertical->show();
        ui->rdo_btn_vertical->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOn1);
        lastKey = key;
    }
    else
    {
        ui->rdo_btn_vertical->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff1);
    }
```

I'm not sure if the expression inside IF statement is a correct way for implementing a masking time.
Any thoughts/suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**

Masking time: it's a time period masked for any threshold checking. This to differentiate positive and negative pulse. See below, during a postive pulse there is a negative-going side but it should not detect as a "negative pulse". That's why I implemented a masking time.

[image]

Comment: What is a _masking time_? What does it mean to _mask_? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ThomasSablik please see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define 2 signal-slots that take care of starting, stopping the elapsed timer,
fortunately, Qt has a class doing this for you, read the doc [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html#start) and be aware of possible overflows and if required set `QElapsedTimer::MonotonicClock`

```
QElapsedTimer timer;
timer.start();
slowOperation1();
qDebug() << "The slow operation took" << timer.elapsed() << "milliseconds";
```

and to trigger the signals

```
if(sensorSignal>THRESHOLD_K)
    emit startTimer();
else
    emit stopTimer();
    
void startTimer()
{   
    timer.start();
}

void stopTimer()
{

    timer.elapsed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the post to add more on masking time. My question is. Once the threshold is reached I need to stop checking for any threshold until the masking time is elapsed (say 0.5 seconds). How do I implement that?

Comment: then u can 1. set a timer for the period "t" and disable the signals until the timer expires :)

Comment: would you like a refernce code for that or are you familiar with QTimers?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not much familiar with QTimer , It will be really helpful if you could share a reference code for that.