# to set a time delay in a IF statement in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I've real-time signal, I need to check if the signal crosses a threshold and set a delay for about 1 second. How do I implement that?

```
if(a_vertical> onThreshold) //what's the expression to set a time delay?
    {
        ui->rdo_btn_vertical->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOn1); // On  LED
    }
    else
    {
        ui->rdo_btn_vertical->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff1); // Off LED
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean for a signal to "cross a threshold"? What's a "real-time signal"? At any rate, there is no sane notion of a time delay in a logical test. Please explain what you want to achieve instead.

Comment: What if the signal goes below the threshold during that second?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for  - but will make your UI unresponsive for that time

Comment: You've already asked what appears to be the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635623/algorithm-for-masking-time-when-the-signal-is-above-a-threshold).  What was wrong with the answer you accepted there?

Comment: Your approach may not work well if you have a noisy signal, like an electronics signal. You might not detect the pulse, but detect a random spike instead, then wait a second and accidentally consider a positive pulse as a negative one. Like so:https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzPcJ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy and dumb solution is to start `QTimer` in single shot mode and check if it's running (should not be) while detecting the pulse. "Easy and dumb" doesn't mean "good".
Depending on the nature of the signal, filtering it might be a viable option.

Comment: how do i check if the timer is running?

Comment: @SruthiDominic https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#isActive